# Photo Competition Template

Tags: discussion, photo-competition

```
Photo Competition: CONTEST_MONTH - CONTEST_THEME

Rules that are always applicable are as follows:

 1. One photo per answer, and no more than 5 answers per user per contest.
 2. Post only photos taken by yourself/person with you.
 3. All entries should include a line of text with the location, subject, and date.
 4. Refrain from posting sensitive/debatable content
 5. Only upvotes count towards winning.

----------
Rules for CONTEST_MONTH are as follows:

 1. **CONTEST_THEME - CONTEST_THEME_DESCRIPTION**
 2. The contest will last the whole month of CONTEST_MONTH and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself.
 3. There is no constraint on when the photo must have been taken.

----------
Suggest a theme for the next contest.

   1. Leave a **single** comment below in the format
      THEME - ONE SENTENCE DESCRIPTION
   2. Upvote the comment(s) with the theme you would like to see next month.

Good luck!
```

I thought I would write up a template for the photo contests to make it easy to create the new one each month.

All one needs to do is copy the above text into your favorite text editor, replace the CONTEST_MONTH with the current month and CONTEST_THEME with the theme of the contest before posting.

Also, if someone would like to suggest a change to the rules, this post would be a better place to discuss them.

Comment: Is this the right question to post some suggested themes for future months?  I have a couple of ideas to throw in.

Comment: @TobySpeight Chat would be better

Comment: I don't think chat would be better, because if there are several suggestions, then we have to go back a month later to see which ones are still in the pool.  My preference would be a Community Wiki answer with a list of suggestions; then each one can be marked `<str>...</str>` when it's used.  Or a question where each suggested theme is an answer.  Actually, I like that better - that would allow voting on the themes.

Comment: @TobySpeight How about each person gets one comment under the current contest where they suggest the theme, and people can upvote the comments that they would like to see next month. That seems the most lightweight solution

Comment: @Charlie, I think that sounds like it's worth trying - let's give it a go and see if it works.

Comment: @TobySpeight See edit

Comment: I guess good themes are ones in which most of the members can participate, so something that presupposes a particular activity or part of the world is likely to do less well.  In other words, try to keep the suggestions fairly general, as the first few themes have been. (That said, "freezing" doesn't happen for large parts of the world, and I didn't see complaints yet).

Comment: Is there a reason for not putting these competitions on the main site? As far as I know, the meta site doesn't get any Google attention. Then you can close the questions, or lock them, after the competition is over. Might go a long way in getting new users to participate.

Comment: @fredsbend That would take a new meta post to change

Comment: @TobySpeight, you clearly missed my complaining in the chat, although I did later find an older photo taken while abroad and did take part in the freezing competition after all.

Answer (score 4):

The idea behind the two sets of rules (as used in the travel stack exchange photo competition which was the inspiration for this) is that the second set can be changed, so one month no people but the other month people can be the focus of the picture. 
If you want the 'no people' rule to always be there, I would move it to the top set, the fixed rules.

Having the template is great, as it allows for more people to post the competition for the next month.
I would however appreciate it when the competition is announced before the previous month is through. Which is the reason the start of posting moment is mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

A general rule (or perhaps guideline) for themes which don't prohibit identifiable people in the pictures:

> Please make sure you have consent of persons pictured to publish your photos of them (even if consent is not legally required).

Comment: Along the same vein, we should perhaps remind users that submitting any pictures on the stack exchange network allows Creative Commons use of said pictures, per stack exchange terms of service.